# Is there a Preload Technique for HTML5 Video like there is for Images?

Tags: javascript, html, video, preload

I have a page that is displaying many (in the thousands) of images and some videos from a constantly updating feed.  In order to make sure that no images or videos are displayed while loading, I want to preload everything in the cache.  Preloading the images has been easy, here is the code I am using for that (after the `.ajax` call has returned to entries).

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function(){
    console.log('imaged loaded to cache');
};
img.onerror = function(){

    console.log('error: bad image source');
};
img.src = url;
```

This has the effect of preloading all of the images to the cache, as I can call a function for the `.onload` event.

I am wondering if there is a similar technique to cache `.mp4` for the html5 video element.  I see that there is a `canplaythough` event that is fired, however, I want to preload movies that from urls that are constantly updating (and will be played in random html5 video elements)

Comment: When the video is a constant stream, you can hardly preload "everything". So what exactly is your criteria for when preloading is finished? A specific number of cached seconds of play-time? Or maybe the `loadedmetadata` or `canplay ` event is what you are looking for?

Comment: I just want to make sure that I do not start playing a video that has not been preloaded enough to play without stalling. `canplaythough` is what I am looking to use.  However, I am trying to do this for many, many of videos (which will be retrieved through ajax), so I am trying to cache them like I would images. The `canplaythough` looks like it is only relevant for 1 video loaded into a specific div.